# Oracle SQL DB import to Excel issues with date formats

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I have a excel file that automatically imports data from an Oracle DB into the sheet. Everything works fine, but date formatting is wrong. In the Oracle DB, the format is 01-JAN-2016. But when it exports to Excel, the format suddenly changes to 1/1/2016.

Is there a good solution to this? Setting the cell format beforehand doesn't work. Once the data is imported, Excel automatically switches format to Date. I have tried a lot but can not solve this issue so I am wondering if any of you have ideas as to what to do. Thanks.

Comment: how are you exporting the data from the database to your sheet?

Comment: Select * from & table then CopyFromRecordSet

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if you're using sql developer or not - you have it tagged, but it sounds like you have an odbc linked data source in excel

Comment: Consider connecting with Get & Transform (aka PowerQuery)

Answer (score 1):

The date isn't *stored* in "01-JAN-2016" format, that's just a representation of the underlying date value.

The recordset contains the *data*, not its representation. Format the column with a `NumberFormat` like `dd-mmm-yyyy`, and 2016/01/01 will look like 01-JAN-2016.

Comment: Excel will automatically switch NumberFormat to Date. I have done some coding to get it as "01-Jan-2016" but even that won't upload back into the database, which is where my issue begins. You can't UCase a date format. Converting the date into a string formatted as dd-MMM-yyyy seems to be a good option to solve this issue, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @tokyo_north if Excel needs to see the date as a date (extremely likely if the query is a data sheet in Excel, that the worksheet needs to use for its purposes), the last thing you want is a string that *looks* like a date and its NumberFormat is essentially irrelevant. No idea what "won't upload back into the database" means, this is a SELECT query, data is coming *from* the database, not *going to* it. You can always add another column and do `=UPPER(TEXT(A2,"dd-mmm-yyyy"))`, where `A2` is your actual-date-value cell - seems Excel still understands that as being a date.